# A rule on subtracting reputation points

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounty

I just wondered why I was subtracted by $100$ reputation points in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44376/juniven?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2016-12-30%2005:40:29Z&page=3) dated May $11, 2013$? I would be glad if somebody explain so I would be aware with this for future purposes. I just wondered why in fact i received  3 votes on that post. Is there a rule I violated? I have totally respect with this site. Mine is, I just want to be clarified.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [timeline](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/388296/11619) reveals that you started a [bounty](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) worth 100 points on that date. The bounties are deducted from the rep tally immediately.

Comment: ♦ Maybe that was the time that I'm exploring the use of the bounty. So far I only remember two offered bounties.

Comment: You can find your current and past bounties from [the appropriate tab on your profile page](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44376/juniven?tab=bounties). A handy feature when you want to revisit some good old stuff.

Comment: ♦ Okay, I got what you mean. But in that post, it was dated May 11,2013 and answered Sept 15, 2013 so it beyond the timeline for the bounty. So, reputation points automatically subtracted?

Comment: The bounties are paid at the instant they are **started**. And, you are paying for extra **exposure** - not for *answers*. Follow up the link about bounties in my answer. It is all explained in the help center. Also check out [past meta threads discussing the details of the bounty system](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bounty).

Comment: It might be useful to link to the post timeline for others to see: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/388296/timeline. More info about the hidden timeline pages: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76566

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As a side question, how to make a timeline appear on a post? Thank you very much.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Look in the URL for the post ID. For example, for this question it is 25538, for the post the bounty was started on 388296. Then look at math.stackexchange.com/posts/<question ID>/timeline (where <question ID> is replaced with the question ID, and there should be no <> in the URL)

Comment: Perfect, I get it now. Thank you very much @wythagoras.

Answer (score 18):

I will just mention that on the very page you linked you can see that the reputation decrease was due to the bounty, together with name of (and link to) the relevant post.

[image: screenshot]